# JSON output on Google app engine

Tags: java, php, android, google-app-engine

please help me out regarding code converting into java.  I have written the following code for the android user and over android i am using JSON. I want to covert the same in java and want to run on Google App engine . I have some what  idea of Google app engine that how to build application on it but i am wondering about this code that how to change it without changing the code on the android

```
mysql_select_db($database_gpConn);


$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

echo '{"earthquakes":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

    mysql_close();
```

Thanks

Comment: You'd need to convert this into a question first.

Comment: Seems like the question is 'how do i convert this code to Java'?

Comment: @Ethan - I can't say that it is or isn't reading it, which is the point. And if it is, that's not a valid SO question either ;)

Comment: Can you say which specific line you don't know how to convert from that (Perl? php?) into Java? Is it that you don't know how to open a connection to the database in Java (btw, you can't, the app engine has a datastore, not an sql database) or is it a problem with JSON? Maybe, break this up into several questions.

Comment: I want to know about this step 


echo '{"earthquakes":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

Comment: @umar he is just returning a nested JSON object, with the results in 'earthquakes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  `$arr[] = $obj;` is taking each query result row as `$obj`, and pushing it to an array `$arr`.  When its finished, `$arr` is converted to a JSON string, and inserted into another JSON string.  The result is a nested JSON with the database rows contained in the 'earthquakes' key.

Comment: Thanks for details but the thing i want to know is that if i want to write same line in java for google app engine then what should i write .

Answer (score 1):

You will have to rewrite it for Google App Engine's datastore model. GAE does not support relational databases: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html#Differences_From_SQL

Comment: i want to have knowledge about this step $arr[] = $obj;
}

echo '{"earthquakes":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

Comment: Take a look at the GSON library: http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson